# Regular expression to check bucketKey can only contain: -_.a-z0-9

Tags: javascript, regex

```
    var reg = new RegExp(/[^-_\.a-z0-9]/g);
  if (!reg.test(bucketKey)) 
  {
    alert('Wrong  Bucketkey format! Please reEnter correct format, valid bucket key can only contain: -_.a-z0-9');
    return;
    }
```

The code seems not to work I have another regular expresssion check but that also don't work. Please help

```
(?=^.{3,63}$)(?!^(\d+\.)+\d+$)(^(([a-z0-9]|[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]*[a-z0-9])\.)*([a-z0-9]|[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]*[a-z0-9])$)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern `[^-_\.a-z0-9]` match characters that are not listed in the range .

So your condition should be `if (reg.test(bucketKey))`

```js
var reg = new RegExp(/[^-_\.a-z0-9]/g);
const bucketKey = ';_a';
if (reg.test(bucketKey)) {
  console.log('Wrong  Bucketkey format!');
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to test for a valid pattern:

```js
const input = [
  'this-is-ok',
  'good_stuff_123',
  'bad@example',
  'space is bad'
];
const regex1 = /^[-_\.a-z0-9]+$/;
const regex2 = /[^-_\.a-z0-9]/;
input.forEach(str => {
  console.log(str + ':');
  console.log('- regex1: ' + regex1.test(str));
  console.log('- regex2: ' + regex2.test(str));
});
```

Output:

```
this-is-ok:
- regex1: true
- regex2: false
good_stuff_123:
- regex1: true
- regex2: false
bad@example:
- regex1: false
- regex2: true
space is bad:
- regex1: false
- regex2: true
```

Notes:

- no need for `new RegExp(/.../)` if you have a fixed regular expression, simply use `/.../`
- regex1 returns true if pattern in valid:

  - `^` ... `$` - anchor at beginning and end
  - `[-_\.a-z0-9]+` - scan for one or more of valid characters (from start to end due to anchors)
- regex2 returns false if pattern in valid:

  - `[^-_\.a-z0-9]` - scan for an invalid character anywhere in the string

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help